# html text tag running into the next line on mobile

Tags: html, text, input, multiline

My code is as follows

```
<div data-role="content" id="div1" align="top" style="padding:3 !important;" >  
        <table border="0" align="CENTER" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="vertical-    align: text-bottom;" >
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <div id="question1" class="question">
                <input type="text" id="question" />
            <Style>
                #question{
                  font:5px;
                  font-family:verdana;
                }
            </style>        
            </div>
        </td></tr><tr>
        <td width="50"><img id="img2" width="40" height="36" style="float:right; margin-top: 0px;" ></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <div class="ui-grid-b" >
                <div class="ui-block-a"><button id="button1" type="submit" data-theme="b" style="font-size:0.8em;"></button></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><button id="button2" type="submit" data-theme="b" style="font-size:0.8em;"></button></div>   
                <div class="ui-block-c"><button id="button3" type="submit" data-theme="b" style="font-size:0.8em;"></button></div>  
            </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

In the block of code above, in the following line of code

```
<input type="text" id="question" />
```

when the value is populated through jQuery, all i'm doing is

```
$('.question').text(questionText);
```

and when I view this in my iPhone, the text goes to the next line when it's longer than the width. I thought textarea was the only HTML tag which has multiline. Not sure why the text here is going multi-line and how do I avoid it? I don't mind the text cutting off but I really don't want it to go multi line.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying `overflow: auto` to the input field

```
<style type="text/css">
    input[type=text] { overflow: auto; }
</style>
```

You might need to set the height of the input element, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve here.  You could set `overflow-x: auto` if you only want it to scroll horizontally or `overflow-y` for vertical scrolling

Comment: overflow: auto didn't work. I tried to do overflow: hidden but that seemed to mess up the UI in a way that the text started showing behind the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

So the way I fixed it for now is, I did the following

```
<div id="question1" class="question" style="height: 12px;">
            <input type="text" id="question" />
        <Style>
            #question{
              font:5px;
              font-family:verdana;
            }
        </style>        
        </div>
```

I atleast got the multi-line to disappear but if there's a more elegant way (jQuery ellipsis seems nice but I didn't get it to work), please let me know.